# JOINKEYS to combine two files

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I would like to explain my scenario using sample code below,

> Two files need to be joined by means
>   of acct# using JOINKEYS but in file1
>   acct# exists at  position:33 but in
>   file2 acct# exists either at
>   position:1 or 2 depends on char 'C' at
>   position:1. In other words if char 'C'
>   exists at position:1 then we need to
>   consider acct# from position:2
>   otherwise consider acct# from
>   position:1. I want do all these things
>   in a SINGLE step.

Hope i made my requirement clear. Appreciate your solution.

```
//STEP010  EXEC PGM=SORT,                      
//             REGION=4096K                    
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//SYSLIST  DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//SYSTOTAL DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//*                                            
//SORTIN   DD  DUMMY                           
//*                                            
//SORTJNF1 DD  *                               
1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3785253347100
2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3785253368600
8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3725826154600
9AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3725817782600
1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3785253347122  
/*                                            
//*                                            
//SORTJNF2 DD  *                               
C3785253347100                                 
C3785253368600                                 
3725826154600  
3725817782600  

//SORTOUT  DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//JNF2CNTL DD  *                               
  INCLUDE COND=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'C'),               
  INREC BUILD=(1,13)                           
/*                                             
//*                                            
//SYSIN    DD  *                               
  JOINKEYS FILES=F1,FIELDS=(33,13,A)           
  JOINKEYS FILES=F2,FIELDS=(01,13,A)           
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1                             
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:01,45,F2:01,13),FILL=C'$'
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                             
/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (notice the JNF2CNTL in-stream):

```
//STEP010  EXEC PGM=SORT,                      
//             REGION=0M                    
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//SYSLIST  DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//SYSTOTAL DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//*                                            
//SORTIN   DD  DUMMY                           
//*                                            
//SORTJNF1 DD  *                               
1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3785253347100
2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3785253368600
8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3725826154600
9AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3725817782600
1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|3785253347122  
/*                                            
//*                                            
//SORTJNF2 DD  *                               
C3785253347100                                 
C3785253368600                                 
3725826154600  
3725817782600  
/*
//SORTOUT  DD  SYSOUT=*                        
//JNF2CNTL DD  *                               
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'C'),FIELDS=(2,13))
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,FIELDS=(1,13))
/*                                                 
//*                                            
//SYSIN    DD  *                               
  JOINKEYS FILES=F1,FIELDS=(33,13,A)           
  JOINKEYS FILES=F2,FIELDS=(01,13,A)
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1                             
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:01,45,F2:01,13),FILL=C'$'
  SORT     FIELDS=COPY                             
/*
```

Comment: FIELDS= is not valid for IFTHEN. Comma missing on first line of INREC. Much better to append a new field for the key, rather than destroying the original data (unless asked to do so).